# How to define one list property that maps to multiple one to manys of shared super type in fluent ef core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-relationship, fluent

First I have a **base class** like this:

```
public class BaseModel
{
      public string Information { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have two **sub classes** of the **base class**:

```
public class SubType1 : BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TestData1 { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}


public class SubType2: BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string TestData2 { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a **parent class** that has a **list** of the **base class**:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<BaseModel> Components { get; set; } = new List<BaseModel>();
}
```

The **Parent** **entity** has **many** **SubType1**s and then also **many** **SubType2**s

**SubType1** and **SubType2** each have their **own table**

What is some **fluent** I could add that would automatically make the **Components** list on the **Parent** entity return all entites from the **SubType1** and **SubType2** tables?

**Key requirement**: Needs to be in fluent

Comment: Whether you are using Entity-Framework or Entity-Framework Core? According to your description, it seems that you are using the [Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines), right? As far as I know, in the EF core, the TPC pattern is [currently on the backlog](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3170), which means that it is being considered for inclusion as a feature, but no date has been set as yet.

Comment: @ZhiLv Yeah that's exactly what I'm looking for, if you want to post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that you are using the [Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines), right?

As far as I know, in the EF core, the TPC pattern is [currently on the backlog](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3170), which means that it is being considered for inclusion as a feature, but no date has been set as yet.